# Create a generic HTML5/CSS3 webpage using Flexible Box Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, webkit

Recently, I have been going through some HTML5/CSS3 tutorials.In one of the tutorials he introduces the Flexible Box Model.To use its features we type `display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center; -webkit-box-flex:1` 
My issue is that I can only use it in Chrome,but I want to write a generic HTML5/CSS3 code that uses this feature and others(shadow,gradient) in IE and Firefox too.

I tried looking up on the net but could not get a satisfactory solution to my problem.

Can someone give any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is not supported in all browsers yet. You can use Flexie as a temporary solution: http://flexiejs.com/. Flexie uses the old (2009) syntax for Flexbox.

Here you can see the browser support for flexbox: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that I can only use it in Chrome

And Safari! Geez.

IE apparently has `-ms-box` from version 10, and Firefox supports [`display: -moz-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-box-flex), but the MDN article mentions that the flexbox spec is expected to be replaced by something else.

I don't think there's any equivalent for earlier browser versions.

Here's an old Mozilla hacks article about it:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

And here's the Can I Use page:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Overall, flexbox seems to be  bit of a crapshoot for everyday use.

Comment: ya I saw about the -ms-box,etc but they don't seem to work.My point is that how should I code my webpage so that it runs on all browsers.

Comment: @user2029727: it won’t run on all browsers. (Although if it’s crucial for your purposes, Flexie from @Martin’s answer is probably worth a go.)